# How to fix themes in ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, kde, theme, dolphin

I am using a Raspberry Pi astronomy package that runs under Arch-Linux and KDE. Amateur astronomers often prefer keeping their computer screens very dark to avoid light pollution.  But my use of this package will be done from indoors with a wifi connection to the Raspberry Pi which sits on the telescope. So keeping it dark is not a concern for me. In fact I often play with the system during the day when bright light makes a dark theme even harder to read,

The designers of this package picked some really weird color themes for certain applications, such as the Dolphin File Manager that comes with the package. I was able to change the theme, but this only applied to the left-pane (which was previously dark), not the right pane, making for a look like this:

[image: Dolphin screen]

There actually is text next to the folders but it's impossible to read.

What config files would I have to change to make a more reasonable color scheme?

Answer (score 0):

Its posible the problem is KDE configuration theme because Dolphin File Manager used this.
In your situation, the issue you're facing with the Dolphin File Manager in KDE might be related to a configuration theme problem, and the core problem could be the legibility of text due to inappropriate color choices. It's possible that the theme or color scheme selected for Dolphin has poor text contrast or readability, making it difficult to view and interact with file and folder names.

To address this issue, you should primarily focus on customizing the color scheme within Dolphin's settings to ensure text and elements are displayed in a way that's more legible and suitable for your needs. If the color scheme settings within Dolphin don't resolve the problem, you can explore system-wide KDE theme and color scheme configurations to make sure that the chosen theme doesn't conflict with Dolphin's appearance. Additionally, you can look for or create custom color schemes that enhance text readability.

Ultimately, the goal is to adjust the theme and color settings to ensure that the text in Dolphin is legible and easy to read for your specific use case.

Comment: I looked and did not find a menu item or gui-button under settings that would enable me to make these changes within Dolphin. I could change what was displayed, different layouts for files and folders and the like, but not color schemes or themes.  If there is an editable config file where I could make such changes, could you tell me what that is? Thanks.